# Merge [material-design-lite] and [material-design-light]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

[material-design-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-design-lite) ▷ 606 questions

[material-design-light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-design-light) ▷ 4 questions ▷ edited/retagged: now zero

The latter is the correct spelling of the word "light" but an incorrect spelling of the former version of the tag. Should they be merged? Or perhaps burninated?

Comment: There's a syn. from `material-design-light` to `material-design-lite` in the very unlikely case someone completely ignores the autocomplete that pops up.